# Some users with IE9 can't edit with TinyMC on Plone 4

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have some users of IE9 who can't edit fields within Plone.

We're on Plone 4 and use the TinyMC as our editor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This temporary workaround was found in the TinyMCE discussions and worked for me (4.0.9).

Go to `portal_skins/plone_templates/main_template.pt`, customize it or edit previously customized `main_template.pt`.

Find the entry:  `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"`

Replace the word `edge` with the number 8 so that it looks like this:

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"
```

This forces IE9 to render TinyMCE javascript in Compatibility Mode (i.e. like it did in IE8). The better fix will be when TinyMCE releases a version that is IE9 friendly.